# Looping through multiple data frames in R

Tags: r

New to R here. I have multiple data frames (with the same variables) from which I want to create subsets from ( by keeping several identical variables).

I saved the name of the data frames by:

```
dfs<-Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)) , ls())
```

I thought I could create subsets by the below:

```
for(d in dfs) {assign(paste0(d,"_subset"), subset(d, select = c(x, y, z)))}
```

But it doesn't look like the "d" in the subset function is recognized as a dataset. Can anyone help?

Comment: more idiomatic/easier to put your data frames in a list and use `lapply` or a `for` loop to operate on the elements, rather than using `get()`+`assign()` ...

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Ben's comment:

You typically know the names of whats in your environment.  Using `ls()` and `get()` will get you that list of data frames in your environment, provided they are the only thing there.  So if there's an `iris` or `mtcars` lying about, it'll grab that too.

So you're better off on creating a explicit list of the data frames that you created.

Once you have that list, you can use a loop, but the more `R` way of doing things would be using the `apply` family of functions, which iterates a function on elements of a list or vector.

In this case you would use `lapply` and an anonymous function so subset each element of your list of data frames.  This will return your list of subsetted data frames.

```
list <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)

lapply(list, function(x) subset(x, select = c(mpg, cyl)))
```